# file upload while edit row in database

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I am working on simple CRUD and I am facing difficulty with the "Edit section"
Long story short:
I have MySQL base with records, I am printing them on the front page, I have added two buttons for "Add new record" via <form and "Edit record" where I can edit any record.
The problem: in the "Add" section I can upload files during adding a new record.
here is the code for uploading a file in insert.php

```
// Include the database configuration file
include 'db.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
}
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','doc','xlsx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        }
```

Via this one, I am uploading the file on the server and making the record into the database as the filename.
I would like to use the same way while editing records in order if the user wants to upload a file later, but when I use the same code I am getting

```
Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 12

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 12
```

Here is my edit.php code:

```
<?php

// include database connection file
include_once("config.php");


// Check if form is submitted for user update, then redirect to homepage after update
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $toolnr=$_POST['toolnr'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $toolname=$_POST['toolname'];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'];
    $usedat=$_POST['usedat'];
    $owner=$_POST['owner'];
    $calibrated=$_POST['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration=$_POST['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors=$_POST['vendors'];
    
    // update tools data
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET toolnr='$toolnr',status='$status',toolname='$toolname',serial='$serial',usedat='$usedat',owner='$owner',calibrated='$calibrated',nextcalibration='$nextcalibration', vendors='$vendors', file_name = '$fileName' WHERE id=$id");

    // Redirect to homepage to display updated tools in list
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php
// Display selected tool data based on id
// Getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Fetech tool data based on id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE id=$id");



while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $toolnr = $user_data['toolnr'];
    $status = $user_data['status'];
    $toolname = $user_data['toolname'];
    $serial = $user_data['serial'];
    $usedat = $user_data['usedat'];
    $owner = $user_data['owner'];
    $calibrated = $user_data['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration = $user_data['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors = $user_data['vendors'];
    
}
?>
```

and here is the HTML pcs:

```
<tr>
                <td>File upload:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" ></td>
            </tr>
```

**---- update ------**
Here is the full edit.php code:

```
<?php

// include database connection file
include_once("config.php");

// Include the database configuration file
include 'db.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
}
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','doc','xlsx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        }

// Check if form is submitted for tool update, then redirect to homepage after update
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $toolnr=$_POST['toolnr'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $toolname=$_POST['toolname'];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'];
    $usedat=$_POST['usedat'];
    $owner=$_POST['owner'];
    $calibrated=$_POST['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration=$_POST['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors=$_POST['vendors'];
    
    // update tool data
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET toolnr='$toolnr',status='$status',toolname='$toolname',serial='$serial',usedat='$usedat',owner='$owner',calibrated='$calibrated',nextcalibration='$nextcalibration', vendors='$vendors',file_name = '$fileName'   WHERE id=$id");

    // Redirect to homepage to display updated tool in list
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php
// Display selected tool data based on id
// Getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Fetech tool data based on id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE id=$id");



while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $toolnr = $user_data['toolnr'];
    $status = $user_data['status'];
    $toolname = $user_data['toolname'];
    $serial = $user_data['serial'];
    $usedat = $user_data['usedat'];
    $owner = $user_data['owner'];
    $calibrated = $user_data['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration = $user_data['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors = $user_data['vendors'];
    
}
?>
```

Maybe I am working in the wrong way somehow...

Comment: Line 12 of edit.php doesn't appear to be related to the error. Are you sure you showed us the right code?

Comment: In the post, the code was divided. I have updated it with full edit.php code.

Comment: Please make sure your form has the the following attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: ` WHERE id=$id`  vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Shame on me... I was missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form.... @DarkBee
Now the functionality is working fine but still getting errors for Undefined array key "file".
Mantykora7 thank you, I will fix it

Comment: `form action` ?? It should look like this `<form action="<?php echo edit.php; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

Comment: add this function `function prx($arr) {echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr);die();}` and then check `prx($_FILES)`

Comment: @Mantykora7 just an FYI: `echo '<pre>'.print($arr, true).'</pre>';` looks cleaner

Comment: another thing is safety: sanitize file name, file permissions, file contains php code, `getimagesize()` returns image size details, but more importantly,  returns false if the file is not actually an image file.

Comment: @DarkBee yes looks cleaner:)

Comment: Team, thank you for the support. The functionality is now working well, but I am still struggling to find how to get rid of the Undefined array key warning.
Even with this Warning the CRUD is working. I am not sure that I get the idea of 
echo '<pre>'.print($arr, true).'</pre>'; on where and how to use it.. can you help me out one more time :)